# recommend new category paths based on factor item matrix and sales of the items

Tags: clustering, recommender-system

Matrix A be a user item matrix. Upon performing  UV decomposition, I have just the V matrix.
The matrix A differs every week and I get a new V matrix every week. The matrix U is not kept track of and I have no information about it.I have access to the sales of the items every 6 months.
I have to predict which items will sell well and what new items can be added to the list that can possibly sell well.